# Stock Price Simulation R code - Slow - Monte Carlo

Tags: r, montecarlo

I need to perform a stock price simulation using R code. The problem is that the code is a little bit slow.
Basically I need to simulate the stock price for each time step (daily) and store it in a matrix.

An example assuming the stock process is Geometric Brownian Motion

```
for(j in 1:100000){
    for(i in 1:252){
        S[i] <- S[i-1]*exp((r-v^2/2)*dt+v*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(1))
    }
    U[j,] <- S
}
```

Any suggestion to improve and speed up the code?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).  Your second for loop will throw an error because `S[i-1]` has zero-length when `i=1`.

Comment: Rewrite your code with `Rcpp` and you will get a speed-up of a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Before going to `Rcpp` I would first try to get rid of the double for loop, and go for vectorisation.

Comment: In addition, you are growing the S and U vector inside the loop, this is very slow. Either preallocate these vectors, or use a solution like @Ferdinand.kraft suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `S[0] = 1`, you can build U as a follows:

```
Ncols <- 252

Nrows <- 100000

U <- matrix(exp((r-v^2/2)*dt+v*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(Ncols*Nrows)), ncol=Ncols, nrow=Nrows)

U <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:Nrows, function(j)cumprod(U[j,])))
```

EDIT: using Joshua's and Ben's suggestions:

product version:

```
U <- matrix(exp((r-v^2/2)*dt+v*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(Ncols*Nrows)), ncol=Ncols, nrow=Nrows)

U <- t(apply(U, 1, cumprod))
```

sum version:

```
V <- matrix((r-v^2/2)*dt+v*sqrt(dt)*rnorm(Ncols*Nrows), ncol=Ncols, nrow=Nrows)

V <- exp( t(apply(V, 1, cumsum)) )
```

EDIT: as suggested by @Paul:

Execution time for each proposal (using 10000 rows instead of 10^5):

Using `apply + cumprod`

```
 user  system elapsed 
0.61    0.01    0.62
```

Using `apply + cumsum`

```
 user  system elapsed 
0.61    0.02    0.63
```

Using OP's original code

```
 user  system elapsed 
67.38    0.00   67.52
```

Notes: The times shown above are the third measures of `system.time`. The first two measures for each code were discarded. I've used `r <- sqrt(2)`, `v <- sqrt(3)` and `dt <- pi`. In his original code, I've also replaced `S[i-1]` for `ifelse(i==1,1,S[i-1])`, and preallocated `U`.

Comment: Can't you replace the last line with `U <- apply(U, 1, cumprod)`?

Comment: you can probably do even better by using `cumsum` on an appropriately scaled `rnorm()` matrix, then exponentiating

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft any indication if, and how much, this solution is faster than what the OP suggested?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, about 2 orders of magnitude faster. See the edit above.

Comment: Hello you all! Thanks a lot for the attention. It´s really much faster using this code.

Comment: I´m now just thinking how could I use these tips, if the stock price, follow a more complex stochastic process.